# Prove that B is logically equivalent to C if and only if B logically implies C and C logically implies B.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

It's exercise 1.8 in Introduction to Mathematical Logic, Sixth Edition by Elliot Mendelson.

I couldn't prove it with the definitions given by the author. How should I approach the problem?

A is said to logically imply B if and only if every truth assignment to the statement letters of A and B that makes A true also makes B true.

A is said to be logically equivalent to B if and only if A and B receive the same truth value under every assignment of truth values to the statement letters of A and B. For example, $A$ and $\neg \neg A$ are logically equivalent.

Below is my proof that feels incorrect.

By proposition 1.1.a, $B \Rightarrow C$ and $C \Rightarrow B$ are tautologies.
Since $B \Rightarrow C$ and $C \Rightarrow B$, $(B \Rightarrow C) \wedge (C
\Rightarrow B)$.
 \begin{array}{lllll}
     B & C & B \Rightarrow C & C \Rightarrow B & (B \Rightarrow C) \wedge (C
     \Rightarrow B)\\
     T & T & T & T & T\\
     T & F & F & T & F\\
     F & T & T & F & F\\
     F & F & T & T & T
   \end{array} 
$(B \Rightarrow C) \wedge (C \Rightarrow B)$ is true if and only if $B$ and
$C$ have the same truth value. Thus, $B$ and $C$ are logically equivalent.

Comment: From where did $C$ enter?

Comment: @GrahamKemp From the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By proposition 1.1.a, $B⇒C$ and $C⇒B$ are tautologies.

No, they are *not* tautologies.  Tautologies are statements that are true for *every* truth value of the atoms.

You then use the definitions given to complete the truth table.  Here's mine.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline B & C & B\to C & C\to B & B\to C \wedge C\to B & B\leftrightarrow C
\\[1ex] \hline \top & \top & \top & \top & \top & \top 
\\[0ex] \top & \bot & \bot & \top & \bot & \bot 
\\[0ex] \bot & \top & \top & \bot & \bot & \bot
\\[0ex] \bot & \bot & \top & \top & \top & \top \\ \hline
\end{array}$$ 
We can then verify that the last two columns are in agreement on every truth assignment.

> $(B⇒C)∧(C⇒B)$ is true if and only if $B$ and $C$ have the same truth value.

Yes.

> Thus, $B$ and $C$ are logically equivalent.

Not quite.  It's "Thus, $B$ and $C$ are logically equivalent *if and only if* $B$ logically implies $C$ and $C$ logically implies $B$".

Which was to be demonstrated.

$\Box$

Answer (score 2):

The definitions should suffice, actually. Trick is to go through all possible assignment of truth values - and for this you have the wonderful tool that is a truth table. Did you get to go over those in the book yet ?

Answer (score 0):

Let us construct the truth table for the statement that $A$ and $\neg\neg A$ are logically equivalent (with $1$ for true and $0$ for false):
\begin{align*}
\text{assignment}&&A&&\neg\neg A&&\text{satisfies condition}\\
======&&===&&===&&==========\\
A=1&&1&&1&&yes\\
A=0&&0&&0&&yes
\end{align*}

Since for all assignments of truth values to all statement letters (in this case, only $A$), the statements (in this case $A$ and $\neg\neg A$) receive the same truth value, they are equivalent given the definition.

Answer (score 0):

You're overthinking this. Suppose $A$ logically implies $B$ and $B$ logically implies $A$. In order for $A$ and $B$ to **not** be logically equivalent, there would need to be a truth assignment making one true and the other false.

Let's say I told you I had an assignment which made $A$ true but made $B$ false. Why would you know I was lying, based on our assumptions about $A$ and $B$?

This handles the direction "two-way logical implication implies logical equivalence." The other direction is even easier ...